# Which Python modules are bundled with SL4A, and how do you add more?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

Which python modules are included with Python 2.6 when you first install [Scripting Layer For Android](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)?

What are the limitations on writing your own modules?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few parts to the question:

- **SL4A Bundle**: Look inside `/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python` to see what SL4A includes. You can easily look in the source, but it's a ZIP file.
- **Pure Python Modules**: You can just drop any pure Python modules on your Python path, which includes the extras directory.
- **Python C Modules**: You can grab a few C dependant libraries, including Twisted, Zope, and PyBluez, as eggs [from PY4A](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/list). You install them with the PY4A app that gets bundled with the Python Interpreter on SL4A. Doing your own eggs is pretty involved, but they have *some* documentation on the same site.